# onChange hook in Ionic Picker component?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I'm using the `IonPicker` component from the Ionic react library. It appears that the only place to access the column's set values is in the `handler` property for any buttons. So I currently deal with the column values in that done handler.

Is there any way to actually hook into the value before a button is pressed? I'd hope for an `onChange` function for either each column or at least for the whole picker component.

Is there such a hook? Perhaps in using `getColumn`, except what's the best way to do that in React?